# Integration of Trajectories in OSM with Leaflet

Tags: javascript, server, leaflet, geojson

I want to insert trajectories (feature collection of linestrings) in my OSM using Leaflet extracted by a Java application. Starting the server, I want to compute those trajectories and transmit them to my OSM. For using geo positions I am working with the GeoJson library from filosganga: https://github.com/filosganga/geogson

Currently, I need a hint how to do that as my following approach leads to an 404 error message saying:

http://localhost:8080/function (data) { linestrings = L.geoJSON([ data ], { style : function(feature) { //console.log(feature); return feature.properties && feature.properties.style; } }); linestrings.addTo(map); }

My html file looks like the following:

```
        var linestrings;
    function reqListener(){
//      var url="/test";
            $.getJSON(function(data) {
                linestrings = L.geoJSON([ data ], {
                    style : function(feature) {
                        //console.log(feature);
                        return feature.properties && feature.properties.style;
                    }   
            });
                linestrings.addTo(map);
    });
    }

    reqListener();
```

My Java based server application is the following:

```
    public void TestClass(){
    get("/test", (request, responce) -> {return Trajectories.writeTestClass(request, responce);});
}
```

It already worked for applications where an OSM based event (mouse click or change of boundary) triggered the extraction and further transmission of geo data to OSM. But this time the Java application should trigger the transmission of those trajectories to OSM.

Any help or hint would be wonderful. Thanks